# How can I test cookies in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I've got file /rspec/support/utilities.rb with method:

```
def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_token
    cookies.signed["remember_token"] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
end
```

But when I run tests, I get this error:

```
undefined method `signed' for Rack::Test::CookieJar
```

So, I guess there is no methods like "signed" and "permanent" in this class, but how can I make tests for cookies then?

Comment: Cookies are a feature of the framework, why would you test them?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, I'm testing controller, that uses cookies.signed["remember_token"]. In my method I have to set cookies.signed if I want correct test

Comment: The thing is `Rack::Test::CookieJar` doesn't support signed cookies. Can you try making it an integration test that runs in the browser and see if it fixes the issue?

Comment: @SlavaNikulin I think you should try this.
https://philna.sh/blog/2020/01/15/test-signed-cookies-in-rails/

Answer (score 1):

You have this question tagged with Capybara, so I'm not really sure whether you're attempting to do controller tests (wouldn't use Capybara) or integration tests (would use capybara).  If you are doing integrations tests using Capybara, you can't set cookies like that.  You would need to go to the login page, click the remember me checkbox and login, then you could use the show_me_the_cookies gem (https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies), which provides a consistent cookies API across multiple Capybara drivers, to check the cookies saved in the browser

Comment: I've already did this. I suspect that Capybara clears its state(session, cookies etc) after each request. I.e. I visit sign_in_path, fill_in all required field, check "remember me" checkbox, and at the next request cookies[:remember_token] will be nil.
 
But I didn't use show_me_the_cookies. Can this gem keep cookies from one request to another?

Comment: No show_me_the_cookies doesn't change the lifespan of cookies.  By request do you mean test scenario, since any test scenario can have multiple requests in it while cookies are cleared between each test scenario. Please update the question to explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate signing in. To do this I need to set cookies.signed, because my controller sets cookies.signed. So, I guess it is impossible because Rack::Test::CookieJar doesn't support signed cookies